# How to add html and css code in WKWebview?

Tags: html, css, swift

I and trying to add html code in swift class and show the page in webView. But It's not showing correctly.

```
let strWebView = """
       <!DOCTYPE> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> <head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /> <title>Index</title> <link href=\"bootstrap.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">          <link href=\"styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js\"></script> <script src=\"js/bootstrap.js\"></script> </head>
         <body>
                    <div class=\"\"><div class=\"\"> <div class=\"container pdf-wrapper\"><div class=\"page-breck\"> <div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-xs-4\"> <div class=\"pdf-top-middle\"> <img src=\"app_logo2.png\" width=\"400rem\" class="center"> </div>  </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5">
                         <p class="contactLft">
                           <b>Name</b> \(strCName)<br>
                           <b>Phone</b> \(phoneNo)<br>
                           <b>Street Address</b> \(strCAddress)
                         </p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-7 text-center">
                         <p class="contactMidText"><b>Subterranean Termite Control/Treatment <br>
                         Retreat and Repair Coverage</b><br>
                         <b>Email</b> \(strEmail)</p>
                       </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add HTML and CSS code to a WKWebView in Swift, you need to load the HTML content into the web view using the `loadHTMLString()` method. Check out the link below:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-load-a-html-string-into-a-wkwebview-or-uiwebview-loadhtmlstring